# Show that the random variable $Y \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda (1-p))$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> We have a fisherman that goes fishing. The number of fishes that bite per hour follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda >0$. When the fish bites, it has a probability $p$ of going away, and $1-p$ of getting caught.
>
> Let $Y$ be the number of fishes that get caught.
> Show that the random variable $Y \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda (1-p))$

Since this problem is in the context of conditional expectation, I proceeded in the following way:

$$\Bbb{P}(Y=y)=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}\{Y=y\})=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}\{Y=y\}|X))=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{P}(Y=y|X))$$

So this is the step in which I get mixed up. Since $Y|X=x \sim Bi(x,(1-p))$ But here I have $Y=y|X$ So what is the real deal?

Comment: If $X$ denotes the number of fishes who bite, you are being told that, for every $y$ and $x$, $$P(Y=y\mid X=x)={x\choose y}(1-p)^yp^{x-y},$$ and are asked for $$P(Y=y)=\sum_xP(Y=y\mid X=x)P(X=x),$$ knowing that, for every $x$, $$P(X=x)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}.$$ Can you finish this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be the no. of fish getting caught and the no. of fish escaping, respectively.

Then $Y+Z\in Poi(\lambda)$ (given).

Thus $$P(Y=k,Z=m)=P(Y=k,Z=m,Y+Z=m+k)=P(Y=k,Z=m|Y+Z=m+k)P(Y+Z=m+k)={m+k\choose m}(1-p)^kp^me^{-\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^{m+k}}{(m+k)!}=\left[\dfrac{e^{-\lambda(1-p)}(\lambda(1-p))^k}{k!}\right]\left[\dfrac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^m}{m!}\right]$$

showing $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and also showing $Y\in Poi(\lambda(1-p))$.

Comment: How can $Y$ and $Z$ be independant? If $k$ is the number of fish that bite, then if $Y=k$, neccesairily, $Z=0$.

Comment: $Y$ is the number of fish that remain caught.